# P:dataTable sorting does not work in ui:decorate

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The p:datatable work fine in standalone but does not work with this situation:
(I am using `Primefaces 6.1` and `mojarra 2.2.9`)

`index.xhtml` code:

```
<h:body>
    <ui:decorate template="/main.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="wrapper">
            <c:if test="#{not empty param['action']}">
               <ui:include src="/templates/param['action'].xhtml" />
            </c:if>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:decorate>
</h:body>
```

The value of `param['action']` is `wrapper.xhtml` code:

```
<body>
    <ui:composition>
            <h:form>
                <p:dataTable var="menu" value="#{customerBean.listMenu}"
                    rowKey="#{menu.menuId}" selectionMode="single">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                         TEST
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:column headerText="Id" sortBy="#{menu.menuId}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{menu.menuId}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Action" sortBy="#{menu.name}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{menu.name}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
    </ui:composition>
</body>
```

The java code:

```
@ManagedBean(name="customerBean")
@RequestScoped
public class CustomerBean {
    @ManagedProperty("#{listMenu}")
    private List<Test> listMenu;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        listMenu = new ArrayList<Test>();
        listMenu.add(new Test("123","Test","A1"));
        listMenu.add(new Test("124","Test2","A12"));
        listMenu.add(new Test("125","Test3","A13"));
    }

    public List<Test> getListMenu() {
        if(listMenu == null){
            init();
        }
        return listMenu;
    }

    public void setListMenu(List<Test> listMenu) {
        this.listMenu = listMenu;
    } 
}
```

When I remove `<c:if test="#{not empty param['action']}">` and hard-coded `/templates/wrapper.xhtml`, it works fine.

Is there any missing steps?

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but when I replace `<c:if test="#{not empty param['action']}">` by `p:panel`, It works fine!